# Subset df within groups for column contained in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df such as:

```
Groups COL1
G1 SP1-3
G1 SP2s
G1 SP4_09
G1 SP7z
G3 SP1_OK
G3 SP1-9
G4 SP1_3
G4 SP2_3
G5 SP3_5
```

I can subset only groups that do contain all the strings in COL1 present in the `list=['SP1','SP2']`

Here I should get :

```
Groups COL1
G1 S1-3
G1 SP2s
G1 SP4_09
G1 SP7z
G4 SP1_3
G4 SP2_3
```

I keep only `G1` and `G4` because they have strings that contains `SP1` and `SP2`. The other do not contain both

I know how to use:

`tab[tab['COL1'].str.contains('SP1')` for instance but I do not know how to include several strings and within groups.

Comment: Why are `G1 S1-3` and `G1 SP4_09` present? Why are `G3 SP1
G3 SP1-9` these not included?

Comment: because I keep a groups if he contains both the `SP1` and `SP2 `strings. The `G3` group is removed because he only contains `SP1` string

Comment: Then why is `SP4_09` included? And why is `SP1_3` included it doesn't contain `SP2`

Comment: Because `SP4_09`is within the G1 wich do contain both `SP1` and `SP2`. `SP1_3` is within the group `G4` wich contain `SP1-9` and  `SP2_3.

Answer (score 1):

IICU

```
s="|".join(list)
tab[tab['COL1'].str.contains(s).groupby(tab['Groups']).transform('all')]
```

Comment: But it will not take into account the groups level, I only whant to remove or keep an antire groupe depending or wether it has all the str in the list or not

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Groups` is the index for your dataframe.

I have a solution where `Groups` is a column.

First, reset the index of the dataframe.

`df1.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)`

Gives:

```
  Groups    COL1
0   G1      SP1-3
1   G1      SP2s
2   G1      SP4_09
3   G1      SP7z
4   G3      SP1
5   G3      SP1-9
6   G4      SP1_3
7   G4      SP2_3
8   G5      SP3_5
```

Now, you check whether all the strings in the list: `strs = ['SP1', 'SP2']` exist in the sum of the strings in `COL1` for each `Group`:

```
groups_to_be_retained = [
    df1.groupby('Groups', as_index=False)['COL1'].sum().loc[i, 'Groups']
     for i in range(len(df1.groupby('Groups', as_index=False)['COL1'].sum()))
    if all(x in df1.groupby('Groups', as_index=False)['COL1'].sum().loc[i, 'COL1']
           for x in strs)
]

print(groups_to_be_retained)
```

Gives:

```
['G1', 'G4']
```

Now, you can either create a new dataframe by subsetting the old dataframe:

```
new_df = df1[df1['Groups'].isin(groups_to_be_retained)]

print(new_df)
```

or

Overwrite the old dataframe with its subset:

```
df1 = df1[df1['Groups'].isin(groups_to_be_retained)]
```

both of which give:

```
    Groups  COL1
0   G1      SP1-3
1   G1      SP2s
2   G1      SP4_09
3   G1      SP7z
6   G4      SP1_3
7   G4      SP2_3
```

Comment: thank you but I have a huge dataframe and this solution takes to much time ...